# Can we catch System exceptions in mule? If not, then how can we handle system exceptions in mule

Tags: exception, mule

There is one similar question but no answers, so I am asking again.
When connection to an external system fails mule invokes system exception strategy. Mule [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/error-handling#system-exceptions) says "When a system exception strategy occurs, Mule sends an exception notification to **registered listeners**, logs the exception, and — if the exception was caused by a connection failure — executes the reconnection strategy. System Exception Strategies are not configurable in Mule". 
My questions:

1. What does **registered listeners** mean here?
2. What is the meaning of "*System Exception Strategies are not configurable in Mule"*?
3. How can I catch the system exception, log it and send an notification email?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does registered listeners mean here?

A registered listener is a separately programmed agent that is registered against mule to process notifications from Mule.

What is the meaning of "System Exception Strategies are not configurable in Mule"?

A System Exception is an exception that is thrown at the system-level where no message is involved - The strategy is how these exceptions are handled and it cannot be altered. This differs from a message-level exception that is thrown from a flow and is caught by a Message Exception Strategy, which is configurable (although there is a default strategy configured) and for which there are a number of documented options.

How can I catch the system exception, log it and send an notification email?

For that you need to create a register a listener. This is discussed in some depth in the documentation.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-server-notifications

There is a good example of the sort of thing that you need to do here -> 
https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/61915/retrieve-java-component-name-in-mulesoft-flow.html

Answer (score 0):

@Jeet,

You can configure the notification Listeners and Loggers in order to catch and notify (by mail for instance) each time a Connection fails.
Check this [link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/mule-server-notifications) for more information on this matter